# Adding graphics to hangman python

Tags: python, graphics

```
Graphics=['''
------------
|         |''','''


------------
|         |         
|          O''','''


------------
|         | 
|          O 
|         / |''','''

------------
|         | 
|          O 
|         / | 
|          | ''','''


------------
|         |
|          O 
|         / |
|          |
|         / | 
|
|            ''']


print("Welcome to Hangman! Guess the mystery word with less than 6 mistakes!")

words= ['utopian','fairy','tree','monday','blue'] 

i=int(input("Please enter a number (0<=number<10) to choose the word in the list: "))

if(words[i]):
    print("The length of the word is: " , len(words[i]))

    guesses=0

    while guesses<6:
        guess=input("Please enter the letter you guess: ")

        guessed=''
        guessed = guessed+guess[0]


        if(guess in words[i]):
            print("The letter is in the word.")
            print(''.join(c if c in guessed else '_' for c in words[i]))


        else:
            print("The letter is not in the word.")
            guesses=guesses+1
            print("Letters matched so far:" ,''.join(c if c in guessed else '_' for c in words[i]))

        if guesses==6:
            print("Failure. The word was:" , words[i])

        else:
            print("You found the word!")
```

One final problem of my Hangman program in Python. Getting the bloody graphics in. This to me is the most challenging part, as I have not dealt with ASCII art through my young experience with Python. Where exactly do I put these graphics into the program? Under the else statement?

Comment: We're unlikely to be able to help you without seeing more context. Could you post your full code here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right.  The graphic should be shown if the player makes a wrong guess.  This is checked in the first `else` block.  So you have to place the code to print the graphic in that block.

Do you need further help on displaying the graphic?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of it as ASCII art so much as an element in the list `Graphics`. You will need to use indexing to access the graphic you want. One way to do that would be to keep track of the failed guesses and then upon each failed guess simply do:

```
print(Graphics[failed_guess])
```

However, you are already keeping track of the number of guesses and incrementing them on failed attempts, so I'd just use that:

```
print(Graphics[guesses])
```

Lastly, it's not typical to name lists with a capital letter. Usually people reserve the capital letters for class-names, and the reasons for this will probably make sense later on. This is one of those, get in the habit of following the common practice and you'll be glad later that you did.

Comment: Okay so I fixed the program up a bit, I put your recommended code in the else block (thank you very much by the way) but I get some sort of index error. builtins.IndexError: list index out of range Any ideas?

Comment: Well, you can't take the index of a list if that index does not exist. From a cursory look, it appears that your `Graphics` list contains 5 elements total. (You can check the length of a list by using the command `len(sample_list)`.) It's also zero-based indexing, so it starts at 0 for the first element and goes up to four (for a list with five elements). Easiest fix: add more graphics to your list.

Comment: I recommend looking into accessing elements via index. Check this out: http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html

Comment: Oh crap, I thought I did have 6 elements in the list... Haha my bad, thanks again!